# Processing list of files and correctly naming the output files

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using the following command line on Ubuntu to try and work through a list of tshark cap files and produce a summary file that is separated. This all works fine. My problem is right at the end

```
sudo ls /capCopy/dump*.cap -l |awk '(NR>0) {print $9}'| xargs -I {} sudo tshark -n -r {} -T fields -E separator=$ -E quote=n -E header=n -e wlan.sa -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal -e  frame.time > /capCopy/dollarSep{}
```

The last element was intended to prepend the characters dollarSep onto the file name that was the source. In the same way that it does in the tshark element.

I can see now that it doesn't work like that and just creates a file name dollarSep{}

Is there a way to pass the source file name forward so I can get what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last command in the pipeline to

```
xargs -I {} sudo bash -c 'tshark -n -r {} ... > /capCopy/dollarSep{}'
```

Comment: Excellent and thanks very much. The answer above almost worked except for my mistake that the directory name "capCopy" is already in the variable pushed into arg. So instead of prepending something on the filename, I appended it. The answer that worked was: sudo ls /capCopy/dump*.cap -l |awk '(NR>0) {print $9}'| xargs -I {} sudo bash -c 'tshark -n -r {} -T fields -E separator=$ -E quote=n -E header=n -e wlan.sa -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal -e  frame.time > {}.dollarSep'